# Roslaunch won't work after moving catkin_ws directory

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to run roslaunch command in my terminal  and when I type my package name and roslaunch file that I want to run it breaks and gives me this error:

```
[controls4Planner.launch] is neither a launch file in package [controls] nor is [controls] a launch file name
```

I'm not sure whats wrong with this and can't seem to figure it out help would be great. Also these problems seem to only occur when I moved all my files into another directory and then I went and replaced all the paths with the new path when catkin_make was complaining.

Using ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04,

EDIT: The problem was when moving my directory that all the paths for my work space didn't work because it pointed to something that wasn't there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140591/roslaunch-won%27t-work-after-moving-catkin_ws-directory/) by [capa_matrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/10396/capa_matrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what seemed to work for me, I edited my .bashrc file specifically the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:~/new_path_to_catkin_ws/src
source ~/path_to_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

This worked and now I can use roslaunch for my ros files! :) Of course the situation for the source would be different for one who uses multiple catkin_ws' as in they'd only source when using the specific ws.

---

Originally posted by [capa_matrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/10396/capa_matrix/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0